# История появления соединительных гласных

Tags: словообразование, морфология, история, морфемика

Известно, что в современном русском языке есть две буквы, обозначающие звуки, стоящие на стыке двух основ в сложных словах: *о* или *е*. Например, _пыл__е__сос_ и _сам_о_лет_.

Почему именно эти звуки составляют интерфиксы русского языка? Каково их происхождение?

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос о соединительных гласных - один из сложных в р.языке. Соединительные гласные о/е - **фонетически обусловленные варианты**.

При слиянии двух основ в одно слово (**морфологический способ сложения**) произносится некий редуцированный гласный, приближенный к о/е, при письме он проясняется: если первая основа сложения оканчивается на парный твердый согласный, то в качестве соединительного гласного выступает о (растворомешалка, водовоз и т. д.); если же первая основа сложения оканчивается на мягкий согласный, на твердый шипящий или ц, то используется соединительный гласный е (мореплаватель, пешеход, овцевод и т. д.). Появление е после твердых шипящих и ц исторически оправдано: шипящие ж, ш и ц были в древнерусском языке мягкими и отвердели лишь в XIV—XV вв., когда отмечаемое словообразовательное правило употребления о/е было уже прочной традицией.

Однако в целом ряде сложных слов, первая основа которых оканчивается на мягкий согласный н, р, т или в, на месте ожидаемого е наблюдается «незаконное» о: коновязь, зверолов, звероподобный, каменотес, каменоломня, честолюбие, властолюбие, костоед, плотоядный, кровообращение, кровопийца, кровожадный, песнопение, баснописец и т. д. Рядом с такого рода словами существуют и слова, где после той же первой основы закономерно появляется соединительный гласный е: коневод, конезавод, камнеобработка, камнерезный, костедробильный, кровеносный, песнетворчество и т. д. Все эти слова являются значительно более поздними образованиями, нежели родственные им по первой основе слова с соединительным гласным о.

О безраздельном господстве словообразовательной модели с о/е в производстве сложных слов свидетельствуют прежде всего многочисленность и разнообразие типов сложений с о/е по сравнению со сложениями без соединительной гласной. Почти все новообразования сложного характера, появившиеся в последнее время (как среди существительных, так и среди прилагательных; в сфере глагола способа сложения не наблюдается), являются словами с соединительными гласными о/е.

http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/soedinitelnyie-glasnyie-68464.html

Соединительные гласные о/е необходимо четко отграничивать от явлений, внешне их напоминающих. Так, слова малоупотребительный, дикорастущий, нижеследующий и т. п., возникающие при помощи **лексико-синтаксического способа** словообразования, соединительных гласных не содержат: о/е в них являются наречными суффиксами (о — словообразующим, е — формообразующим). В словах автозавод, велогонка, авторегулятор, метеосводка о является такой же неотъемлемой частью сокращенных основ (автомобильный, велосипедная, автоматический, метеорологическая), как согласные ф, т, р в словах профсоюз, партактив, зарплата.

Соединительные гласные о/е как значимые части слова могут быть выделены, естественно, только в том случае, если анализируемое слово осознается как сложное. Если же слово пережило процесс опрощения или переразложения, то никаких связочных морфем в нем нет. Так, не выделяются уже в качестве значимых морфем соединительные гласные в словах столпотворение (возникло путем эллипсиса на базе фразеологического оборота вавилонское столпотворение), дикобраз (сложение дикий и образ), кругозор (сложение круг и зор — от зреть), психолог, библиотека и т. д. Соединительного гласного нет в некоторых сложных словах, испытавших процесс выпадения одного из слогов, например: табакур, знаменосец (первоначально табакокур, знаменоносец).

Времяисчисление, семядоля, сорвиголова. Я в словах ВРЕМЯ и СЕМЯ – окончание, И в глаголе СОРВИ – суффикс повелительного наклонения, но в сложных словах эти элементы выполняют  роль соединительную, это интерфиксы.

Интерфиксы могут быть соединительными элементами и при других способах словообразования сложных лексем, например: пятитонка, семитонный.

Интерфиксов, являющихся соединительным элементом в лексемах сложных, в языке нашем довольно много:

•   -И-: вертишейка, горицвет; пятнадцатилетний, пятиколёсный;

•   -А-: сорокалетний, сорокаэтажный, сумасшедший;

•   -Я-: времяпрепровождение, семявместилище, имянаречение, имяславие;

•   -УХ-: двухколёсный, двухъярусный, двухподъездный;

•   -У-: двумерный, двусторонний, двуокись;

•   -ЁХ-: трехэтажный, трёхведёрный, трёхъязычный;

•   -О-: труднодоступный, быстрорастворимый;

•   -Е-: нижеподписавшиеся, вышесказанное.

Answer (score 0):

(Недостаточно для ответа, но слишком много для комментария.)

П.Я. Черных в "Очерке русской исторической лексикологии" говорит следующее.

> С общеславянской и с дославянской эпохи употребляется  в славянских
>   языках и другой способ образования новых слов  путем сложения разных
>   основ, причем имеется несколько видов  таких образований. Всегда в
>   славянских языках существовало  сложение основ с соединительным
>   гласным, **о**, **е** типа листопад  (общеславянское народное название
>   месяца октября). ... Этот прием  сложения основ является единственно
>   продуктивным и в наши  дни: *теплоход*, *землечерпалка* и т. п.

Ещё гугло-книги находят в трудах какого-то университета такое:

> Ученые предполагают, что соединительные гласные возникли из флексий
>   -о-основ.

Но ни трудов, ни более широкого контекста найти не удалось.

Это всё, что мне удалось узнать поиском.